# React multi-word search

Tags: reactjs, regex, search, react-hooks

I am researching how I can do a multi-word search. I found this example [Multi Term Filter with hooks](https://codepen.io/kaiserbock/pen/zWBZLK).

```
const filterIt = (terms, arr) => {
  if ("" === terms || terms.length < 3) return arr;
  const words = terms.match(/\w+|"[^"]+"/g);
  words.push(terms);
  return arr.filter((a) => {
    const v = Object.values(a);
    const f = JSON.stringify(v).toLowerCase();

    return words.every(val => f.includes(val));
  });
};

const FilteredList = () => {
  const [items, setItems] = useState([]);

  const filterList = useCallback(({target}) => {
    const searchQuery = target.value.toLowerCase();
    const updatedList = filterIt(searchQuery, initialItems);
    setItems(updatedList);
  }, []);
```

I'm trying to modify it so that I can separate words with a space. For example, I enter "iron suit", and the search gave me:

[image]

At the moment, the search does not return anything:

[image]

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Not sure I understand... currently the search will split your query search by space and search those individual words; and what you want is to be able to have space in your query? For example, instead of searching for `iron` and `suit`, you want to search for `iron suit`?

Comment: If that's the case ^, you need to define another "separator" for your query, like a comma `,` or something else.

Comment: @BrunoMonteiro I want to do a search on multiple words that do not follow each other. For example, I enter the first word, I get the result with it. I enter another word through a space, and I search for this word as a result of the search for the first word. Now search searches for the second word only if it comes after the first word separated by a space.

Comment: Hmm that's an odd behavior for a search. Usually your app will search for everything that is in the search bar. If you want a new search, the common behavior is to "clear" the first word and then type the second word.

Comment: Is this kind of what you want? https://codepen.io/brunomont/pen/ExKYdjQ?editors=0010

Comment: @BrunoMonteiro yes, this is what i wanted, thanks a lot!

Comment: @BrunoMonteiro but now the query "chain urban" returns all results that contain the word "chain".

Comment: @Rox was the answer helpful for you?

Comment: @Rox I thought that by searching "chain urban" you wanted all results that contain "chain" and "urban", no? Maybe I am missing something...

Answer (score 0):

I played a bit with your sample code and came up with this:

```
const filterIt = (terms, arr) => {
  if ("" === terms || terms.length < 3) return arr;
  var words = terms.match(/"[^"]+"|\w+/g);
  
  words = words.map(val => val.replace(/\"/g, ""));
  //words.push(terms);
  
  return arr.filter((a) => {
    const v = Object.values(a);
    const f = JSON.stringify(v).toLowerCase();

    return words.every(val => f.includes(val));
  });
};
```

which allows me to search without quotes

[image]

and with quotes

[image]